# How can I automatically upload a release into Codeplex?

Tags: msbuild, codeplex

I'm imagining something like 
 `msbuild /t:CodeplexRelease`
which would build, then upload the outputs to the specified Codeplex project.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's documentation on using the "CodePlex MSBuild Tasks" for creating and uploading files for a new release: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodePlexMSBuildTasks&referringTitle=CodePlexAPI

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to write a [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) that uses [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), but as far as I know CodePlex doesn't have an API for such automated tasks.

Comment: Apparently, IT DOES EXIST.  see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341758/how-can-i-automatically-upload-a-release-into-codeplex/2393332#2393332

Answer (score 0):

**[Setting up a continuous integration server for a CodePlex project](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/)**

**[SNAK - The Simple NAnt Acceleration Kit](http://snak.codeplex.com/)**

**[Getting Continuous Integration Working With CodePlex: Part III](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/2175/Getting-Continuous-Integration-Working-With-CodePlex-Part-III.aspx)**

that should get you started.

Comment: Interesting, but not exactly what I was talking about.